# How to probe the availability of Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, avx, basm

How can I check using Delphi 2007 that a box is AVX capable.

*My question is only restricted to querying the support in the CPU* (Assumption is made that the OS is OK / Windows 7 with SP1).

The PDF document entitled [Introduction to Intel® Advanced Vector Extensions](http://software.intel.com/file/37205)
by Chris Lomont explains how to do it and provides an example code implementation but in c++.

It's also available at this [page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions/).

Comment: Just FYI, BASM (at least for Delphi XE2) does not yet support AVX instructions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a translation of the assembler code given on an [Intel blog](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/04/14/is-avx-enabled/):

```
function isAvxSupported: Boolean;
asm
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
    push ebx
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
    mov r10, rbx
{$ENDIF}
    xor eax, eax
    cpuid
    cmp eax, 1
    jb @not_supported
    mov eax, 1
    cpuid
    and ecx, 018000000h
    cmp ecx, 018000000h
    jne @not_supported
    xor ecx, ecx
    db 0Fh, 01h, 0D0h //XGETBV
    and eax, 110b
    cmp eax, 110b
    jne @not_supported
    mov eax, 1
    jmp @done
@not_supported:
    xor eax, eax
@done:
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
    pop ebx
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
    mov rbx, r10
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

This code will work in both 32 and 64 bit versions of Delphi.

**Update**: Register saving code added thanks to @PhiS.

Comment: Thank you David ! My understanding of the piece of code is that the `XGETBV` instruction is not supported by Delphi, is that so ?

Comment: That's right. I found the magic db here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80128

Comment: Good lucking porting this to X64 alone. :-)

Comment: I think it's better with the X64 version. If someone asks the same question for X64 I'd rather have your upvotes all in one place for the same topic.

Comment: @Warren Actually the x64 version is identical since x86 register calling convention returns values in EAX, and x64 calling convention returns values in RAX. And we are only using EAX/ECX registers which are both volatile on both ABIs.

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I could +1 2x.

Comment: David, this code will only _almost_ work on x64 and x86. The thing is CPUID also sets EBX, so you need to save/retore EBX (since Delphi requires this). Now if you do that by PUSH/POP EBX, that will not compile on Win64, because it expects PUSH + reg64 ...

Comment: ... so you'll probably have to IFDEF that. I'd recommend to save RBX in an unused register on X64, e.g. in R10

Comment: I run the code using D2007, it crashes on machine that does not support AVX. However, if the code is compiled at XE8-32bit, it works fine

Comment: i found out the the compiler directive CPUX86, CPUX64 is added after XE2   http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)